# Find a regular expression that searches for a specific pattern in a file (Unix-Solaris)

Tags: linux, unix, expression, solaris

I have this file. Its a number at the start, then a name and a surname (someone can have 2 names or/and 2 surnames but not more)

```
21501 Sylvester Stallone                 
21502 Tommy Lee Jones                        
21503 Jean Claude Van Damme
```

I have to use `grep`. So far I have thought these 2 option I'm almost 100% sure none of them is right but it's a start.

```
grep -e [0-9]\{5\}[[:space:]][A-Z][a-z]

grep  '^([a-z]+)[ \s]([a-z]+)/n'
```

Comment: `{` and `[` have special meaning to the shell, you need to put the regexp in quotes.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: what should be the structure of the expression. If one or them is right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -E -i '^[0-9]{5}( [a-z]+){2,4}$' filename
```

`^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the line. Then it looks for 5 digits, followed by 2-4 names each preceded by a space. `$` anchors it to the end of the line.

`-E` makes it use extended regular expressions, and `-i` makes it case-insensitive so you don't need to say `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Thank you. It made everything very clear to me. Have a nice day!